# Voldemort replication and failover details

Tags: replication, failover, voldemort

I'm evaluating Voldemort and encountered some confusing stuff related to replication and failover. I tried to make a simple 2 nodes cluster configuration where each node is a backup for another one. So data written to node 1 should be replicated to node 2 and vice versa. In case of node 1 failover the second node should serve client requests. After node 1 recovery data should be transfered back to node 1. I think it's very common and clear case. So I made the following configuration.

```
<cluster>
        <name>perf_cluster</name>

        <server>
                <id>0</id>
                <host>10.50.3.156</host>
                <http-port>8081</http-port>
                <socket-port>6666</socket-port>
                <admin-port>6667</admin-port>
                <partitions>0, 1, 2, 3</partitions>
                <zone-id>0</zone-id>
        </server>

        <server>
                <id>1</id>
                <host>10.50.3.157</host>
                <http-port>8081</http-port>
                <socket-port>6666</socket-port>
                <admin-port>6667</admin-port>
                <partitions>4, 5, 6, 7</partitions>
                <zone-id>0</zone-id>
        </server>
</cluster>

<stores>
  <store>
    <name>perftest</name>
    <persistence>memory</persistence>
    <description>Performance Test store</description>
    <owners>owner</owners>
    <routing>client</routing>
    <replication-factor>2</replication-factor>
    <required-reads>1</required-reads>
    <required-writes>1</required-writes>
    <key-serializer>
      <type>string</type>
    </key-serializer>
    <value-serializer>
      <type>java-serialization</type>
    </value-serializer>
  </store>
</stores>
```

I perform the following test:

- Start both nodes;
- Connect cluster via shell using 'bin/voldemort-shell.sh perftest tcp://10.50.3.156:6666';
- Put the key-value "1" "a";
- Perform 'preflist "1"' which returns me 'Node 1' 'Node 0' so I assume that 'get' request will be sent to Node 1 first;
- Crash Node 1;
- Get key "1". I see some errors related to loss of connectivity but finally it returns me correct value;
- Start Node 1;
- Get key "1". It says that Node 1 is available but returns me 'null' instead of the value. So I assume the Node 1 didn't get the data from Node 0 and since my required-reads = 1 it doesn't ask for Node 0 and returns me null.
- Crash Node 0;
- Key "1" is lost forever because it wasn't replicated to Node 1.

I'm more than sure that I misunderstand something in configuration or cluster replication details. Could you clarify why the data doesn't replicate back from Node 0 to Node 1 after recovery? And am I right that replication is a client responsibility, not server? If so how should the data be replicated after Node recovery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't known if you've already solved the problem, but take a look to: http://code.google.com/p/project-voldemort/issues/detail?id=246

Remember that the memory store is only for testing (junit) purposes, you should use the readonly or bdb stores.

Comment: I didn't solve it the way I wanted. I found some scripts in Voldemort to perform manual cluster synchronization. Not good for me, I hoped Voldemort would do it automatically on start.

Comment: Voldemort is synchronizing (replication-factor) automatically. As the case I showed states, the replication seems to not work fine with consecutive partitions. Please use the script to generate your partitions and remove the whole zone configurations, so you simplify your test case